# How to add "date accessed" or "date retrieved" in BibLaTeX?

Tags: bibliographies, urls

I have the following in `.bib` file:

```
@online{solarfarm, 
author = {Buckley, Alastair and nee Hall, Lisa Clark and {Colantuono, Giuseppe Everard}, Aldous}, 
file = {:Users/Desktop/Downloaded/85c4687c.html:html}, 
title = {{The Sheffield Solar Farm}}, 
Howpublished = {\url{http://www.sheffieldsolarfarm.group.shef.ac.uk/solar-panel-data}}, 
url = {\url{http://www.sheffieldsolarfarm.group.shef.ac.uk/solar-panel-data}}, 
urldate = {16/5/2013} 
}
```

but I can't get the `date retrieved` or `date accessed` to work, it never shows up in references.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand\bibname{References} 
\bibliographystyle{abbrv}    
\bibliography{library}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `abbrv` style doesn't know those fields.

Comment: Agree with @MarcoDaniel , `note` field is useful for date accessed. e.g. in harvard system simply enter [Date accessed: 2013].

Comment: @oLas Where is Note field ?

Comment: @egreg I want to order them alphabetically though

Comment: see the link from @MarcoDaniel, I'm confident this will answer your question, if it does I'm sure an upvote would be appreciated over there!

Comment: @oLas Surely there's a simpler way than using terminal to edit each reference manually right ?!

Comment: Ok, so terminal is only used to get information on what fields are AVAILABLE for a particular bibliography style. I noticed that you wanted your references listed alphabetically, in that case I would suggest using the Harvard referencing system `\bibliographystyle{agsm}` which DOES have a note field. Then, simply add a note to each reference `note = {[Date accessed: 2013]}` to comply with Harvard standards.

Comment: @oLas Im using numeral in-text referencing, and want to order them alphabetically in references. Would I retain these using the method you provided ?

Answer (score 22):

Your question is not clear. Do you want to use package `biblatex` or not?  Some of your comments make me think you mixed up BibTeX, `biblatex` and principles of building `bib` files.

The following MWE shows you the usage of `biblatex` with some package options to controll the layout of your bibliography.  What you at last need you can read in the manual of package `biblatex`, try `texdoc biblatex`.

Please have a look on the comments in my MWE.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{solarfarm, 
  author  = {Buckley, Alastair and nee Hall, Lisa Clark and {Colantuono, Giuseppe Everard}, Aldous}, 
  file    = {:Users/Desktop/Downloaded/85c4687c.html:html}, 
  title   = {{The Sheffield Solar Farm}}, 
  url     = {http://www.sheffieldsolarfarm.group.shef.ac.uk/solar-panel-data}, 
  urldate = {2013-05-16}, 
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[%
  backend=bibtex      % biber or bibtex
%,style=authoryear    % Alphabeticalsch
 ,style=numeric-comp  % numerical-compressed
 ,sorting=none        % no sorting
 ,sortcites=true      % some other example options ...
 ,block=none
 ,indexing=false
 ,citereset=none
 ,isbn=true
 ,url=true
 ,doi=true            % prints doi
 ,natbib=true         % if you need natbib functions
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}  % better than \bibliography

\begin{document}
Text \cite{solarfarm} Text.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The result will be:
[image]

Comment: Is it possible to change the american date formate 05/16/2013 to a european format: 16.05.2013?

Comment: @Sorry, was offline. Try package [`isodate`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/isodate).

Answer (score 12):

you say you want to make biblatex use the `urldate` field, but the most important thing seems to be missing from your example: `\usepackage{biblatex}`. ...if you really want to use biblatex: your MWE and your question (title, tags) provide conflicting information.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[sorting=nyt,firstinits=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{testbib.bib}
@online{solarfarm,
author = {Buckley, Alastair and nee Hall, Lisa Clark and {Colantuono, Giuseppe Everard}, Aldous},
file = {:Users/Desktop/Downloaded/85c4687c.html:html},
title = {{The Sheffield Solar Farm}},
url = {http://www.sheffieldsolarfarm.group.shef.ac.uk/solar-panel-data},
urldate = {2013-05-16}
}
@online{solarfarm2,
author = {Auckley, Alastair and nee Hall, Lisa Clark and {Colantuono, Giuseppe Everard}, Aldous},
file = {:Users/Desktop/Downloaded/85c4687c.html:html},
title = {{The Sheffield Solar Farm}},
url = {http://www.sheffieldsolarfarm.group.shef.ac.uk/solar-panel-data},
urldate = {2013-05-16}
}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliography{testbib.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{solarfarm}
\cite{solarfarm2}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Biblatex will print the URL's date automatically, so if an `urldate` field is present, no further action is required.
[image]

Comment: But I want to use the .bib file, not manually insert it there

Comment: sure, but you're the only one who actually *has* your bib file. *We* need to create it via `filecontents`, for testing and demonstration purposes. You may simply remove that section. In other words: that `filecontents` section has nothing to do with the problem your question relates to. It's all about properly loading the biblatex package.

Comment: ...unless that `biblatex` in your question title is a mistake, i.e. you're not intending to use biblatex at all.

Comment: I tried adding that package and I get an error saying that the .bbl file was not created by biblatex .. I'm using Mendeley to organise my references. Is that causing a problem ?

Comment: don't know much about Mendeley, but if that's the tool that creates your .bib files, that's not going to cause that problem. The .bbl file might be a leftover from the time before you inserted `biblatex`. You can safely delete it (it's a temporary file that's re-created as required), and thus give biblatex a chance to create a new one that it can work with.

Comment: I did that and I got another error saying `Package biblatex Error \bibliographystyle invalid - 1048 \bibliographystyle{abbrv}`

Comment: @Razor: what Kurt said, plus: if you want to give `biblatex` a try, use, for example, the code example I gave you, without modifiying it; see if it works without any errors; and then start modifying it to suit your taste. If you simply take a line like `\usepackage{biblatex}` and insert it into your above example, things are not going to work (as you've noticed already).