# BibLatex MLA showing Accessed date in a weird format

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-mla

I would like for my MLA citations to show the accessed date at the end of the citation, after the URL. I would like to get the same result shown in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/111631).

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openany]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[style=mla,showmedium=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\mainmatter
The word "university" comes from the Latin \textit{universitas} stemming from \textit{universus}, universe \parencite{Universe2010}.
    
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Here is the bib file:

```
@inreference{Universe2010,
  title = {Universe, n.},
  booktitle = {{{OED Online}}},
  date = {2010},
  edition = {Third Edition},
  publisher = {{Oxford University Press}},
  url = {https://www-oed-com.janus.bis-sorbonne.fr/view/Entry/214800#eid16692141},
  urldate = {2020-06-25}
}
```

Here is the result I am having: [image]

The "accessed date" is stuck between the date of the document and the URL and I have no idea why.

I tried using `mla-new` instead, which displays the citation correctly, but unfortunately my university requires for citations to show the locations and it seems that it is not possible yet with the `mla-new` style (if someone knows how to do that, I would be interested as well).

Final note: I am a total LaTeX beginner, please bear with me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer you linked to shows the URL+`urldate` output of the standard `biblatex` styles. You can overwrite the `mla` definitions with the relevant bits from `biblatex.def`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openany]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=mla,showmedium=false]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibparens{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}}
\renewbibmacro*{url+urldate}{%
  \usebibmacro{url}%
  \iffieldundef{urlyear}
    {}
    {\setunit*{\addspace}%
     \usebibmacro{urldate}}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inreference{Universe2010,
  title     = {Universe, n.},
  booktitle = {{OED Online}},
  date      = {2010},
  edition   = {Third Edition},
  publisher = {{Oxford University Press}},
  url       = {https://www-oed-com.janus.bis-sorbonne.fr/view/Entry/214800#eid16692141},
  urldate   = {2020-06-25},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
\mainmatter
The word \enquote{university} comes from the Latin \textit{universitas}
stemming from \textit{universus}, universe \parencite{Universe2010}.
    
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: “Universe, n.” OED Online. Third Edition. Oxford University Press, 2010. https://www-oed-com.janus.bis-sorbonne.fr/view/Entry/214800#eid16692141 (visited on 25 June 2020).]

Comment: thank you, it worked!